# Sites folder icon is incorrect in Finder sidebar on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: mac, osx-lion, icons, finder

I recently did a clean install of Mac OS X Lion. Now, I can't figure out why the icon for the `Sites` folder in the finder sidebar is just a regular folder and not the special `Sites` icon it used to be.

My sidebar currently looks like this:

[image: sidebar]

However, when I "Get Info" for the `Sites` folder, the icon preview is this:

[image: info]

Any ideas why the icon is just a regular folder icon as opposed to the special `Sites` icon it used to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of OS X Lion, the `~/Sites` folder does no longer have its own sidebar icon. And also as of Lion, Finder ignores custom folder and volume icons completely for presentation in the sidebar.

Check out the contents of `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents` for all sidebar icons (names starting with `Sidebar`). While there is a `SitesFolderIcon.icns`, there is no `SidebarSitesFolder.icns` or anything like that.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks! so how would I create a `SidebarSitesFolder.icns`?

Comment: @Hristo You can't. The existing ones are hard-coded.

Comment: ohhh... well that's not cool :(

Comment: @Hristo There are [hacks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooD4QF68G8s) to fix this (and also get color icons in the sidebar back), but I don't think they're worth the possible problems.

Comment: thanks for the link, but I agree... it's not worth the hassle nor the potential problems that could arise